# Are there any model checkers or proof systems for the Pi Calculus

Tags: algorithm, proof, model-checking, pi-calculus

I have become mildly obsessed with Milner's Pi Calculus, and while I can have lots of fun drawing out little diagrams on my whiteboard, I was curious if there are any good (or bad even) modeling systems for it to do checking against your logic, in a similar fashion to something like TLA+.

If such a system does not exist or is not necessary due to `reason x`, I would love an explanation to why if possible.

Comment: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/38414/determinism-and-pi-calculus is a good starting place

Comment: @btilly I think I should clarify; I'm not asking in regards to anything especially theoretical, but instead in regards to a computerized system to check against something I write down, similar to the TLMC thing for TLA+, or the Coq proof assistant.

Comment: According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_model_checking_tools), there exist several mu-calculus solvers but I don't see any pi-calculus model checker being listed. However, a quick search in google of keywords "pi-calculus model checker" reveals that apparently "pi-calculus" model checking has been done in the past, since there seems to be some papers about it. The prism model checker is mentioned in one of these search results, though I did not investigate any deeper than this. Did you try googling these resources yourself? why are these not fit for your own case?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I actually did start googling it for myself, and while I found a lot of those papers that you are referring to, I had trouble actually finding any implementations that I could download and use, indicating to me that the stuff they were talking about was probably proof-of concept.  As a result, I was hoping that someone had something semi-idiomatic that perhaps could have been found by using a different keyword or something.